# Error in the regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

Regexp :

```
preg_match('#^(\\w+)( | array )(\\w+)(?:|\\=(.*))$#', $line, $mtch)
```

Text :

```
integer  udg_plc = 0
integer array udg_time
string array udg_plname
player  array udg_dlforpl
multiboard udg_LastTable= null
integer array udg_kill1
```

As a result there is no matches. How to correct?

Comment: What it is necessary to know? need  that the regular expression would find every line from the provided text.

Comment: First of all, you're using PHP which means you don't need to use double backslashes, so use `\w+`. Also you don't need to escape `=`, which means just use `=`. Apart from that, what are you trying to match ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there are more than 1 space in your input

```
/^(\w+)( +| +array +)(\w+)(?:| +\=(.*))$/
```

Use `+` quantifier to match 1 to many spaces